# Can rocket engine like NERVA be used to get into low earth orbit or higher?

Tags: nuclear

I have heard of nuclear propulsion, however I wonder that is it possible for it to launch into space, and if so, how much fuel would it need?

Comment: Is "to space" a verb? As in, "to launch into"? Well, I like it, anyway. NERVA produced 75,000 pounds of force. SpaceX's Merlin engine produces 94,000 pounds at sea level, which is a bit higher, but comparable. So maybe, depending on the size of the rocket. But they used liquid hydrogen and were meant for upper stages and space tugs, not first stages.

Comment: @Greg the NERVA weighs about 15 times more than the Merlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [NERVA](http://www.astronautix.com/n/nervaalphaengine.html) was a fairly heavy engine, with a thrust to weight ratio of about 3:1 in flight configuration (as compared to ratios of better than 100 for liquid-fueled engines). Between that and the fact that its exhaust included radioactive material, it wouldn't have been a good choice for a lower-stage engine, but it would have been possible. Improved nuclear-thermal engine designs like [Project Timberwind](http://www.astronautix.com/t/timberwind.html) could have achieved 30:1 TWR, but the cost and environmental issues would still make it a poor choice for a first stage.

Fuel efficiency of a nuclear-thermal engine is about twice as good as a hydrogen-oxygen combustion rocket, so you'd need only half as much fuel mass as your hydrogen-oxygen-fueled competition as a rule of thumb, but the fines from the [EPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Environmental_Protection_Agency) would easily wipe out any cost savings.

Comment: Any idea about Alan Bond's Scorpion design? using a lithium loop to avoid contaminating the propellant (and generate copious amounts of electricity) removes the radioactive exhaust issue.